# Get all the combinations of given lists having N items in each list without duplicate?

Tags: python-3.x, combinations

Given list is

```
`test1List = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']`
```

Let's say, N = 4,

then I am searching for all the combinations created from test1List with following conditions:
there won't be duplication of element in one combination
same element can be in another combination with different order
should output for N times of elements on list.

I have tried combinations, permutations and product methods and searched on all existing solutions but I haven't found any solution regarding my issue and I tried my self to do it, but I am loosing the logical parts in it. So, please help me to find out the solution.

Here is an example which will help to demonstrate my output:
Let's say N = 4

```
`['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`

`['B', 'A', 'C', 'D']` (element not in order way, but can't be repeated once element is added)

`['A', 'B', 'D', 'C']`

`'D', 'A', 'E', 'C']`
```

Mostly, I found in order ways, so I am having issue on it.

Thank you in advance for any kind of solutions and information.

Comment: I don't understand. Is `['B', 'A', 'C', 'D']` a valid output or invalid output?

Comment: yes, it is also the valid output. Every solution i find out was in order like

Comment: If that's the case then what's the problem with `itertools.permutations(test1List, 4)`? (`import itertools` should be placed at the top of the python file first)

Comment: Please show the whole expected output for that example input. Or if it's too large, use a small enough input to show the whole output.

Comment: I didn't believe, it seems to solve my issue. There were no repetition and in unordered also. I was making simple problem into complex one.  Thanks alot.